# При нажатии на кнопку не сдвигаться картинка влево

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на кнопку должно сдвигаться картинка влево, но ничего не происходит. В чём ошибка?

https://jsfiddle.net/v730d40d/

```js
document.getElementById('slider-left').onclick = turn();

function turn() {
  var line = document.getElementById("line");
  line.style.left = -128 + "px";
}
```

```css
#slider {
  width: 384px;
  height: 128px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#line {
  background-color: red;
  width: 896px;
  position: relative;
}

#line img {
  float: left;
}

#line::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div id="line">
    <img src="img/die.png" alt="1">
    <img src="img/happy.png" alt="2">
    <img src="img/lol.png" alt="3">
    <img src="img/sleep.png" alt="4">
    <img src="img/smile.png" alt="5">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="slider-left">Turn left</button>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как куда-нибудь передать функцию // почему событие вызывается сразу же?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719926/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b6%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

При назначении функции не нужно ее вызывать.

Замените `document.getElementById('slider-left').onclick=turn();`
на `document.getElementById('slider-left').onclick=turn;`

С вызовом функции присваивается то, что она возвращает, а т.к. в ней нет return ваш код равен этому:
`document.getElementById('slider-left').onclick=undefined;`

Также, нужно дождаться загрузки DOM'а, чтобы `#slider-left` был доступен.

Рабочий код: (на jQuery DOMContentLoaded вызываться не будет)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('slider-left').onclick=turn;
}

function turn(){
    var line = document.getElementById("line");
    line.style.left = -128 + "px";
}
```

Comment: Всё равно выдаёт ошибку   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at script.js:1

Comment: @DenisShestopalov Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Если вы только начинаете работать с событиями – обратите внимание на следующие особенности.

Функция должна быть присвоена как turn, а не turn().

```
element.onclick = turn;
```

Если добавить скобки, то turn() – будет уже результат выполнения функции (а так как в ней нет return, то в onclick попадёт undefined). Нам же нужна именно функция.

*Дополнительная информация*

…А вот в разметке как раз скобки нужны:

```
<input type="button" id="slider-left" onclick="turn()" />
```

Это различие просто объяснить. При создании обработчика браузером из атрибута, он автоматически создает функцию из его содержимого. Поэтому последний пример – фактически то же самое, что:

`element.onclick = function() {
  turn(); // содержимое атрибута
};`

Comment: А почему тогда, когда я повешал в html событие onclick функция сработала, а когда в jsе это сделал, то не сработало, хотя я копировал уже правильный код?

Comment: Поместите Ваш js код сюда: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { ваш код});` Таким образом Ваш js код сперва дождётся формирования DOM дерева, а потом выполнится. Иначе ему ещё не будут доступны элементы 'slider-left' и 'line'.

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать так

```js
document.getElementById('slider-left').onclick = function turn(){
 document.getElementById('line').style.left = -128+'px';
}
```

```css
#slider{
 width: 384px;
 height: 128px;
 border: 5px solid #000;
 margin: 50px auto;
}

#line{
 background-color: red;
 width: 896px;
 position: relative;
}

#line img{
 
 float: left;
}

#line::after{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="slider">
  <div id="line">
   <img src="img/die.png" alt="1">
   <img src="img/happy.png" alt="2">
   <img src="img/lol.png" alt="3">
   <img src="img/sleep.png" alt="4">
   <img src="img/smile.png" alt="5">
  </div>
 </div>

 <button id="slider-left">Turn left</button>
</body>
</html>
```